# Intel Edison node.js sample code not working with BMP 180 - gy68 barometer

Tags: javascript, node.js, sensors, intel-edison

This is the sample code from Intel for running a barometer.

```js
//Load Barometer module
var bmpx8x = require('jsupm_bmpx8x');
// load this on i2c
var myBarometerObj = new bmpx8x.BMPX8X(0, bmpx8x.ADDR);
var pressure, temperature, altitude, sealevel;

// Print the pressure, altitude, sea level, and
// temperature values every 0.1 seconds
setInterval(function()
{
 var pressure = myBarometerObj.getPressure();
 var temperature = myBarometerObj.getTemperature();
 var altitude = myBarometerObj.getAltitude();
 var sealevel = myBarometerObj.getSealevelPressure();

 var BMPX8Xresults = "pressure value = " + pressure;
 BMPX8Xresults += ", altitude value = " + altitude;
 BMPX8Xresults += ", sealevel value = " + sealevel;
 BMPX8Xresults += ", temperature = " + temperature;
 console.log(BMPX8Xresults);
}, 100);

// Print message when exiting
process.on('SIGINT', function()
{
 console.log("Exiting...");
 process.exit(0);
});
```

but when I execute this code, the error below is thrown.

```
var myBarometerObj = new bmpx8x.BMPX8X(0, bmpx8x.ADDR);
                     ^
Error: Illegal arguments for construction of _exports_BMPX8X
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/root/bmpx8x.js:31:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: Do you have a link to the sample source? And did you have any issues with `CMake` on `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post but I might have an answer for this for future reference cause I encountered the same problem.

In my case I was receiving the same error when trying to connect a BMP180 sensor to the I2C6 on the Edison Mini breakout board.

Here are some steps that might solve the problem:

Run the following command:
`$ i2cdetect -y -r 6`

If it produces an error you need to configure your pins with the following commands:

```
$ echo 27 > /sys/class/gpio/export
$ echo 28 > /sys/class/gpio/export
$ echo mode1 > /sys/kernel/debug/gpio_debug/gpio27/current_pinmux
$ echo mode1 > /sys/kernel/debug/gpio_debug/gpio28/current_pinmux
```

Also make sure your sensor is connected, otherwise you will get a remote I/O error. You can debug theese errors with:

`$ journalctl -f`

If you are using I2C6 you need to set your first argument to 6, otherwise it will default to bus 1.

You might want to try updating your mraa library aswell, just in case.